# How does my Getcookie function reads a cookie from document.cookie string?

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody please help me understand what is going on in Getcookie function. I am trying to get my in-depth understanding of whats happening in every single line of code.

```
function Getcookie(name) {

var dc = ";" + document.cookie
var start = dc.indexOf(";" + name + "=")

if(start == -1) return false

start += name.length + 2 // Why is 2 being added here 
var end = dc.indexOf(";", start)
end = (end == -1) ? dc.length: end

return decodeURI(dc.substring(start, end));

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand? Most of the lines are really simple.

Comment: Are you familiar with the format of `document.cookie`?

Comment: `Why is 2 being added here` - because `";" + name + "="` ... `;=` is two characters

Answer (score 0):

The only real question I see is "Why is 2 being added here".

The `document.cookie` looks like this:

```
name1=value1;name2=value2;name3=value3...
```

If `name = "name2"`, `start` will be the index of `;name2=` in that string, and we want to get `value2`. To get from the beginning of that string to the end, we add the length of `name2`, and then an additional `2` for the `;` and `=` characters. Now `start` points just past the `=` character, which is the beginning of the `value`.

After that, we search for the next `;` character and set `end` to its index. If it's not found, we set it to `dc.length` (you have a typo there, `dec` should be `dc`). Then the value is everything from `start` to `end`.

Comment: sorry for the typo